# How to create a directory with a sub directory dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually i want to create code builder which can create a module name which is user defined from system
What happens here is ,
I have input field where i type the name of the module. and once we click the submit button
it creates the folder in the directory ,with sub folder like controller,model and views.

How can This be implented in codeignator?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use mkdir function in php? for example I input myfolder in your text field.. then just mkdir the main folder then after that mkdir the controller, model, view.

if(!is_dir('/data/public_html/myfolder'))  // to check if folder does not exist
mkdir('/data/public_html/myfolder', 0755);

if(!is_dir('/data/public_html/myfolder/models'))  // to check if folder does not exist
mkdir('/data/public_html/myfolder/models', 0755);

if(!is_dir('/data/public_html/myfolder/views'))  // to check if folder does not exist
mkdir('/data/public_html/myfolder/views', 0755);

if(!is_dir('/data/public_html/myfolder/controllers'))  // to check if folder does not exist
mkdir('/data/public_html/myfolder/controllers', 0755);

Comment: Please don't create folders with 0777 chmod in your system like that.

Comment: oh my bad, just a copied example just showing that the 2nd parameter will be a permission